# Expected expression Pylance error in If Condition

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, pylance

I am trying to insert the API query response in to the SQL server database. On a particular field I need to check if the value of the field on the Query response is true or false , if it is false I need to insert 'F'  if its true I need to insert 'T' a field in DB

```
    cursor = sqlconn.cursor()
    for index,row in roomsDF.iterrows():
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO SurplusMouse.RM_Room(ROOMID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, SHIPPING_FREEZE, UPDATEDNAME)\
                                    values(?,?,?,?,?)"

                        ,row['id']
                        ,row['name']
                        ,row['description']
                        , if row['shippingFreeze'] == false:
                             'F' 
                         else: 
                             'T'
                        ,row['shippingFreeze'].split(' ', 1)
                    )
```

I see two errors here one on the `cursor.execute("` as `"(" was not closed` and another issue is  `Expected expression Pylance` erroron the `if` . This is my first Python script and not sure if I am missing something any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are mixing two different concepts. You need to divide and conquer.

1. Retrieve the data, and create a variable for each value.

   ```
    id = row['id']
    name = row['name']
    shippingFreeze = 'T' if row['shippingFreeze'] else 'F'
   ```
2. Then, create the execute command. Make sure that the shippingFreeze attribute comes correctly formatted as boolean.

Regards

L.

Comment: where would I assign this variables?

Comment: I assume you have the desired data in your array: roomsDF. And you are traversing it, row by row. Now, at the start of the for loop (just before the cursor.execute() you need to get the values.